# displaying database values in ListView (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have some values in my database and I want to display them in a ListView. **Here is my java code:**

```
public class mallList extends Activity {

protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected ListAdapter adapter;
protected ListView listOfMalls;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.malllist);

    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    listOfMalls = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
}

public void searchMall(View view) {
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT mall FROM restaurants", null);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.mall_list_item, cursor, new String[] {"mall"}, new int[] {R.id.mallview});
    listOfMalls.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

**and here is the malllist.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

           <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                android:text="Search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="searchMall"/>
           </LinearLayout>

     <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to happen is for the searchMall to be called when the search button is clicked, but whenever I click on the search button it says *The application (myappname) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.* Can anybody help?

Comment: check your logs and post the error (I know others may answer i did not look at the code)

Comment: this is what the error says:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fdm/com.fdm.mallList}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: Are you sure `mall_list_item` has a `TextView` with id `mallview`?